# IF and OR Formula for Is Running User

Tags: formula

I'm trying to figure out how to add to an exiting IF statement formula that is working to detect running user. I want to review multiple user lookups on a project and if the user populated in the lookup is the running user in any of the lookups, then it should result in a 1 as true.

Formula that is working = `IF( ActivityOwner__c = $User.Id , 1 , 0)`

```
IF( 
    OR(
        sitetracker__Project_Manager__c = $User.Id ,
        Admin__c = $User.Id, 
        Lease_Administrator__c = $User.Id 
        ActivityOwner__c = $User.Id
    1,
    0
))
```

Can I combine to compare all 4 at once?

Answer (score 1):

You could use CONTAINS:

```
IF(
  CONTAINS(
    sitetracker__Project_Manager__c&':'&
    Admin__c&':'&
    Lease_Administrator__c&':'&
    ActivityOwner__c,
    $User.Id),
 1,
 0
)
```

The `&` operator is a string concatenation.

Comment: This will work but if we short circuit with OR it will run faster. Correct me if my assumption is not correct

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty The difference in "speed" can't be measured, but in terms of "compiled size", this formula should be quite a bit smaller.

Answer (score 0):

IF syntax is this

```
 IF(
    CONDITION,
    TRUE,
    FALSE
    )
```

Your formula has syntax errors please try this

```
IF( 
    OR( sitetracker__Project_Manager__c = $User.Id , 
        Admin__c = $User.Id, 
        Lease_Administrator__c = $User.Id, 
        ActivityOwner__c = $User.Id 
      ),
      1,
      0
 )
```